# Calculate the hypotenuse of a right triangle using an array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm having issues with an assignment and I hope someone out there would be able to assist.  The goal is to use a multidimensional-array to have the user put in side1 and side2 of the right triangle to figure out the hypotenuse.  Right now I'm stuck at two points:

- How to set the array with variables
- How to save those variables to the array and process the equation

My code currently looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

double hypotenuse(double x, double y, double z);

int main(void)
{

    double side1, side2, side3, counter;
    side3 = 1;
    int table[4][3] =
    {
/* Column 0  1  2 */
        { 1, 2, 3 }, // Initializers for for indexed by 0 or row 1
        { 4, 5, 6 }, // Initializers for for indexed by 1 or row 2
        { 7, 8, 9 }, // Initializers for for indexed by 2 or row 3
        { 10, 11, 12 } // Initializers for for indexed by 3 or row 4
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++);
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("Table [%d] [%d] = %d \n", i, j, table[i][j]);
        }
    }


    for (counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++) {
        printf("Enter values for two sides: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf", &side1, &side2);

        printf("%.2f\n", hypotenuse(side1, side2, side3));
    }

    return 0;
}

double hypotenuse(double x, double y, double z) {
    x *= x;
    y *= y;
    z = sqrt(x + y);

    return z;
}
```

Right now line 26 has an error of i not being defined, which I don't understand how it isn't since line 22 should have defined it, or so I thought.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!
~CRob

Comment: Pay attention to your use of semicolons.

Comment: turn for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++); into for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)

Comment: Aside: the `hypotenuse` function looks as though it will calculate in 3D space but the `z` is only used as a local variable by the function, and its input value is ignored.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest removing the statement: `#include <string.h>`

Comment: You gave some line numbers where you think the problem is located, but by the time we put you code into our editor,.we have no idea if our line numbers match your line numbers.  Please post a comment on those lines that you think have a problem.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  I.E. 2, 3, 4.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest giving those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, perhaps via `#define` statements, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. properly checks for (and handles) errors
3. formatted for user readability
4. produces the desired functionality

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf(), fprintf(), scanf()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(0, ESIT_FAILURE
//#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>     // sqrt()

#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 3
#define NUM_CALCULATIONS 3

double hypotenuse( double x, double y );

int main( void )
{

    double side1;
    double side2;

    int table[ ROWS ][ COLS ] =
    {
/* Column 0  1  2 */
        { 1, 2, 3 },    // Initializers for for indexed by 0 or row 1
        { 4, 5, 6 },    // Initializers for for indexed by 1 or row 2
        { 7, 8, 9 },    // Initializers for for indexed by 2 or row 3
        { 10, 11, 12 }  // Initializers for for indexed by 3 or row 4
    };

    // display table to user
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            printf("Table [%d] [%d] = %d \n", i, j, table[i][j]);
        }
        puts( "" );
    }

    // input triangle legs, then display hyp to user
    for ( size_t counter = 0; counter < NUM_CALCULATIONS; counter++) 
    {
        printf("Enter values for two sides: ");

        if( scanf( "%lf %lf", &side1, &side2 ) != 2 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to read the two user inputs, exiting\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        printf( "%.2f\n", hypotenuse( side1, side2 ) );
    }

    return 0;
}

double hypotenuse( double x, double y )
{
    x *= x;
    y *= y;
    return  sqrt(x + y);
}
```

a typical run of the program results in:

```
Table [0] [0] = 1 
Table [0] [1] = 2 
Table [0] [2] = 3 

Table [1] [0] = 4 
Table [1] [1] = 5 
Table [1] [2] = 6 

Table [2] [0] = 7 
Table [2] [1] = 8 
Table [2] [2] = 9 

Table [3] [0] = 10 
Table [3] [1] = 11 
Table [3] [2] = 12 

Enter values for two sides: 6 7
9.22
Enter values for two sides: 2 3
3.61
Enter values for two sides: 3 4
5.00
```